# pip is not found with python 2.7.12 source

Tags: python-2.7, pip

According to this documentation (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) pip is included with python 2.7.9 or later. I compiled python source downloaded from https://www.python.org/ but pip is not found in the build directory or not in `/usr/local/bin` after installing.

Used:

```
./configure --enable-shared --with-ensurepip=yes
```

option for build configuration, in centos 6.8, where python 2.6 is already installed, and I couldn't uninstall it because of dependency issues.

Comment: Perhaps that 'pip is already installed if you're using Python 2 >=2.7.9 or Python 3 >=3.4 downloaded from python.org' refers to windows and Mac OS X binary installers.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem, `python 2.7.12` in an Ubuntu system responded `/usr/bin/python: No module named pip`.

I ran `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get install python-pip`, then I got the problem solved.